# How can I identify the conductors in an appliance cord with only the green wire colored?

Tags: electrical, appliances

I've bought an appliance power cord for my dishwasher, however, unlike this cable:

[image]

*(my car was parked)*

only the green (ground) cable is colored.

Does this mean that when I connect the cord to the appliance, the black and white wires are in fact interchangeable?

Is this because it is AC?

Comment: Make sure you're using a cord approved for this use.  The conductors have to be the appropriate size for the load.

Comment: Honestly, ignore the old cable and use the either the wires you will connect the cord to or the screw terminals as your guide.  If the old cable was wire capped to a set of wires, then you should see black, white & green inside the wiring box of the dishwasher.  
Wire to like colors.  If there are terminals, then they should be marked.  If you have questions about which wire goes where, take a picture of the terminal posts and post it.  I'm sure someone will then tell you where black, white & green goes.

Comment: @diceless - If you read the question, the **new cord** has **NO** color coding except for the ground wire.

Comment: @Fiasco, You're right, my bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look for another identifier besides color such as a **stripe** or **rib** on one of the two other wires. That will be the **Neutral** wire. Make sure it connects to the **Wide** blade on the plug.

*Is this because it is AC?* No, if it isn't so identified, you are dealing with a cheap knockoff pigtail that probably belongs in the waste bin. In the 120V single phase world, Neutral is effectively at ground potential, therefore if you touch it, you shouldn't get shocked. Hot while alternating isn't at ground potential and so the voltage is alternating between +120V and -120V (RMS, actual voltage peak ±170V), making you the conductor if you connect the hot wire to the dishwasher chassis and you touch it and ground. If the neutral connects to ground in the dishwasher, you've just connected up a dead short.

As this is for a dishwasher, neutral must connect to neutral and hot to hot, any mess-up here is going to be ugly. The only other method is to use an ohmmeter to trace which wire is attached to which blade. Normally narrow blade hot, wide blade neutral and ground pin to ground. If there is no difference in blade widths, then use the socket chart below to figure out which blade is Hot and Neutral from its position and attach the wire to the appropriate terminal in the appliance.

There is only one instance where the connections could be considered even remotely "interchangeable" and that is on a double insulated device where neutral is totally and completely isolated from ground.

NEMA **socket** listing with blade width and "polarity". Note that NEMA 5-15 and 5-20 can be installed with the ground prong up (coat hanger excluder mode) so right and left slot position is relative.

[image]

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 4 Equipment for General Use
>
> #### Article 400 Flexible Cords and Cables
>
> #### *II. Construction Specifications*
>
> **400.22 Grounded-Conductor Identification.** One conductor of flexible cords that is intended to be used as a grounded circuit conductor shall have a continuous marker that readily distinguishes it from the other conductor or conductors. The identification shall consist of one of the methods indicated in 400.22(A) through (F).
>
> **(A) Colored Braid.** A braid finished to show a white or gray color and the braid on the other conductor or conductors finished to show a readily distinguishable solid color or colors.
>
> **(B) Tracer in Braid.** A tracer in a braid of any color contrasting with that of the braid and no tracer in the braid of the other conductor or conductors. No tracer shall be used in the braid of any conductor of a flexible cord that contains a conductor having a braid finished to show white or gray.
>
> **(C) Colored Insulation.** A white or gray insulation on one conductor and insulation of a readily distinguishable color or colors on the other conductor or conductors for cords having no braids on the individual conductors. For jacketed cords furnished with appliances, one conductor having its insulation colored light blue, with the other conductors having their insulation of a readily distinguishable color other than white or gray.
>
> **(D) Colored Separator.** A white or gray separator on one conductor and a separator of a readily distinguishable solid color on the other conductor or conductors of cords having insulation on the individual conductors integral with the jacket.
>
> **(E) Tinned Conductors.** One conductor having the individual strands tinned and the other conductor or conductors having the individual strands untinned for cords having insulation on the individual conductors integral with the jacket.
>
> **(F) Surface Marking.** One or more ridges, grooves, or white stripes located on the exterior of the cord so as to identify one conductor for cords having insulation on the individual conductors integral with the jacket.

Comment: I did not downvote this because everything else is basically correct, except that the ribbed conductor is the neutral, the smooth is the hot.

Comment: Oh, crud, I knew that and flubbed it. Thanks for not downvoting, making the fix right now.

Comment: Oh yeah, I keep forgetting. I could have just edited. Duh me.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I've edited in the relevant NEC section, feel free to remove it if you like.

Comment: Small correction: hot actually alternates from +170V to -170V. 120V is the [RMS average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square).

Comment: @Tester101 - yes, good information to include, straight from the source since it would help with all cords, not just 3-wire.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - Since most people are familiar with the nominal voltage, I left it at that. Brings back memories of discovering Average, Effective and Peak to Peak voltage and power equations. I chose not to confuse people who haven't been exposed, but given insulation factors, it's not bad to point out you want good insulation because the peak is quite a bit higher than nominal.

Comment: I want to add that the OP can take a multimeter if available and use continuity mode with the NEMA chart you added, by touching one lead of the multimeter to a polarity blade and the other end to each wire, whichever wire beeps is the winner.

Comment: Cords which have a ground pin don't typically have one blade wider than the other.

Comment: @BradGilbert - true. Will update.